# Why TextClock calculate time minus now%1000

Tags: android, text, time, operating-system

When reading `TextClock` source code I found following code:

```
private final Runnable mTicker = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        onTimeChanged();

        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);//Why?

        getHandler().postAtTime(mTicker, next);
    }
};
```

I just cannot understand why not use `next = now + 1000`?
Many thanks for help.

Comment: It's getting the time in milliseconds. The way it calculates `next` is just rounding it to the next whole second; i.e., the next millisecond time that ends in `000`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much, you are right. TextClock wants to keep up with the real time.